# why this dijit.form doesnt submit?

Tags: javascript, forms, dojo

Why this form wont submit?

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="myForm" data-dojo-id="myForm"
encType="multipart/form-data" action="Cart.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="searchName" 
data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true" id="searchName" />
<input type="radio" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton" name="sl" id="radioOne"    value="full"/> <label for="radioOne">Full</label>
<input type="radio" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton" name="sl" id="radioTwo" value="short"/> <label for="radioTwo">Short</label>
Data Select
<select name="select1" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
<option  value="2">Data1</option>
<option  value="1">Data2</option>
</select>
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" name="submitButton"     value="Submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Some javascript too:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad:true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
dojo.require("dijit/layout/AccordionContainer"); 
dojo.require("dijit/layout/BorderContainer");
dojo.require("dijit/layout/ContentPane");
    </script>
```

Maybe its a stupid question, but ive been looking at it several hours and still cant figure it out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you meet by *won't submit*. I moved your code into JS Bin (http://jsbin.com/iziwen/1/edit) and it works fine:

[image]

If you experience problems on the server side I suggest you change `encType="multipart/form-data"` to `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` (or do not use it at all as it is the default value) - you do not need `multipart/form-data`, you are not sending files (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)).

If this won't help, please specify *won't submit* more precisely.

**EDIT:** I do not use `dijit/form/Form` submit functionality, I just grab form data and send those via XHR to my web service, but I had a look at how submit functionality works and it seems so you need an `<iframe>` to use submit functionality. So this is what I changed:

A. Form definition - `target:"formSubmitIframe"` points to iframe id:

```
<form
    id="myForm"
    data-dojo-id="myForm"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form"  
    data-dojo-props="action:'Cart.php', method:'post', target:'formSubmitIframe'"
>
```

B. Added iframe:

```
<iframe name="formSubmitIframe" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Once all works for you add `style="display:none;"` to iframe to hide it.

See it in action in JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/iziwen/7/edit

**N.B.:** I do not recommend submitting a form this way. If you do not need to go cross-domain or sending files, simply get form data via `var data = dijit.byId("myForm").get("value")`, so you will have form data in JSON and then send them up via `dojo/xhr` or `dojo/request` (for dojo 1.8+).

Also `dojo/xhr` is capable to send form just by providing a form id to it - here is a nice example: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/xhr

Comment: Oh sorry, by wont submit i mean that doesnt jump to action (cart.php) and dont know why. Im kind of new with DOJO, maybe i need something extra in the javascript part?

Comment: Submitting form this way does not seem to be the best choice. I edited my answer to provide alternatives. Hope it will help.